# Is $\partial(A-B)\cup \partial(A \cup B) \supseteq \partial(A)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $A$ is open. Is it true that $\partial(A-B)\cup \partial(A \cup B) \supseteq \partial(A)$? This is a bit difficult.

Comment: Just take $B = X$, where $X$ is the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general.

For example, if you are in $\mathbb{R}$, $A = ]0, 1[$, $B = \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$

$A - B = \emptyset$

Thus:

$\partial A = \{0, 1\}$, $\partial(A - B) = \partial (A \cup B) = \emptyset$

Hence $\partial A$ is not included in $\partial(A - B) \cup \partial (A \cup B)$.

You can find other counter examples in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well.